# Can I prevent browser extensions from logging messages to the Firefox console?

Tags: firefox, debug

The error messages generated by the web page I'm building are being drowned in a ton of console messages that are being produced by browser addons/extensions.

Can I limit the console messages to be only those from the actual *web page*?

Answer (score -1):

See no answer there. Better than nothing for those who'll see this post in the future, there is a no-addons option on a lot of web browser when launched from a terminal. This should prevents you from receiving a ton of debug messages.

Comment: This option is called `-safe-mode` in Firefox.